# javascript: Scrolling a child window

Tags: javascript

I have a church site I'm managing. It uses Vimeo to host the live and recorded masses.

Rather than split the live mass and recorded masses to separate pages, they have the live mass with recorded masses directly below that on the same page.

I've pointed the link for live and recorded masses to the same Vimeo page.

The problem is that parishioners are an older crowd and missing the fact that they need to scroll down in order to see the recorded masses. They are complaining that the link for recorded masses takes them to the live mass page.

I want to use some JavaScript to force the new window to scroll. Is this possible?

I tried using `window.open` to open the window then scrolling it down to the recorded content:

```
function popp() {
  loc = "https://vimeo.com/user/page";
  var win = window.open(loc, "window");
  win.scroll(200, 0);
}
```

for some reason the window does not scroll. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I imagine vimeo probably has a way to embed videos if you wanted to just include them on the page itself rather than embeding the whole page.

Comment: I was doing that but they were growing tired waiting for me to get around to posting each week. Now they are hosting recorded videos on Vimeo and simply want me to point to that page.